# How to change the background color of an image in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

In my program, I need to add some images on the GUI. However, the background color of the image is not the same as the background color of the view. 
I know that there is a property used to change the image background. However, when I change the feature of this item, there is nothing happen. Do I miss some settings before adding the image on the project such that I cannot change the background color of the image? Thank you so much for your emergent help!

Comment: what do you mean by background here for the imageview or the background of the image?

Comment: Which property you are used for changing the background color of the image ?

Answer (score 1):

Change of *ImageView's* background is possible, but not of Image's.

You can do it by specifying the desired color of ImageView.

```
[imageViewName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Or you can specify the RGB values.

```
[imageViewName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.0 blue:1 alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the background of the image. But you can change the background color of imageview that contains the image.